# Responsive sidebar resize issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, resize, sidebar

```
<div class="column col-sm-2 col-xs-1" id="sidebar">

asdasdas
```

```
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azqdYX
```

I simply can't get around hiding left sidebar when size is getting smaller, anyone got anything?

When it comes to 768- width I want the sidebar to be hidden.

using bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the break point for the collapse nav like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```